# Will TCP Server retransmit SYN+ACK if Client is not reachable?

Tags: networking, tcp, tcpclient, tcpserver

Assume the scenario that TCP client(**A**) sent **SYN** to the TCP Sever(**B**) and then TCP Client disconnected from the network, here TCP Server will be in the state **SYN-RCVD** how that TCP Server will know that Client is not reachable??

will TCP Server retransmit SYN+ACK ??

(Aif yes, How many times Server will retransmit **SYN+ACK**??

if no, How much time Server will remain in **SYN-RCVD** state??
[image]

Comment: 'Disconnected' doesn't have any meaning here. The client is trying to *connect*. There is no connection to disconnect yet. The only way it can disconnect is by ceasing to try to connect. The SYN/ACK will be retried a few times subject to slow-start and all the rest of it, just like any other TCP segment. Off topic.

Comment: 'Closed' doesn't have any more meaning than 'disconnect'. There is no TCP client to close until the connection is established. Possibly you just mean 'went away'. Still off topic.

Comment: @EJP my doubt is that after retrying few times will TCP-Server goes to CLOSED state or will it be in LISTEN state ??

Comment: Not one word of that appears in your actual question. The listening port will remain in LISTEN state. The half-connection created by the initial SYN will be dropped and disappear altogether.

Comment: @EJP can you please tell me that when TCP SERVER will go to CLOSED state ??

Comment: CLOSED state doesn't really exist. It just means that the port has been released. 'TCP Server' doesn't really mean anything either. A TCP *port* will 'go to CLOSED state' via any of a large number of transistions, which you will find in RFC 793.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> will TCP Server retransmit SYN+ACK ??

Yes

> How many times Server will retransmit SYN+ACK??

Depends on OS configuration.

In Linux:
   [/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_synack_retries](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/tcp.7.html)

In windows: [HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\TcpMaxConnectResponseRetransmissions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938208.aspx)

> How much time Server will remain in SYN-RCVD state??

Until the last retransmit of SYN-ACK timeouts. 
Usually over 3 minutes.